# Export Sharepoint list to .csv and upload to Azure Data Lake Using Flow

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-lake, power-automate

I am trying to using Microsoft Flow to export a Sharepoint List to Azure Data Lake.

I want it so that anytime a particular online list is changed, its entire contents are loaded into a file in Data Lake. If the file already exists, I want to overwrite it. Can someone please explain how I can go about doing this, I have tried multiple ways, but they are not getting the job done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the items in the SharePoint list to near perfection. I will post the Flow here in case anyone in the future needs it.

[image: Flow Solution]

So what I did is that every 5 minutes I "create" a file in Azure Data Lake which overwrites the file if it exists. The content of the files cannot be blank, so I added a newline to the content. Then I use Get Items to retrieve all the items in the SharePoint List. From there, using an Apply to each loop, I append the content of the current row of the Sharepoint list to the Data Lake file (separated by | and ending with a new line after all the content is added). This works to near perfection, with the only caveat being the newline at the beginning of the file, which I eliminate using PowerQuery.

This is exactly what I needed. If anybody sees a way to make this better, please post so that we can get this to perfection.